# Code Composer Studio (CCS), importing existing project fails: "Compiler definition not available"

Tags: eclipse, texas-instruments, code-composer

Attempting to import an existing project into CCS, I get the error:

> Import failed for project  because its compiler definition
>   is not available. The project does not appear to be a 'CCS Project'.
>   Please try importing it through the 'General > Existing Projects into
>   Workspace' wizard.

I have done a lot of digging and finally have it half solved I think.  The `.cproject` had a 3rd configuration to the build for unit tests; removing this was one of the key steps.  Along the way I discovered a peculiar behavior:

1) Eclipse/CCS seems to remember that a project failed to import, and no matter what you do to fix it it will refuse (I've tried a lot of things).  Once the name of the project in the `.project` file is changed, Eclipse/CCS will "give it another chance" and import it. (I didn't try restarting Eclipse, maybe that might work too)

2) Eclipse/CCS also seems to remember that a project succeed to import.  If I removed the recently imported project, then put back the configuration for unit tests in the .cproject file, then re-import, it succeeds!  Seemingly ignoring whatever the original problem was.

I have yet to sift through the 3rd configuration settings to find out exactly what triggers the import failure.  But I can't help thinking that somebody else must have seen this.  I've found lots of questions on the TI website, but no explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue but not sure it was for the same reasons. I'll share my story in case it helps answer your question. I've been working with CCS6.1.x for a while building a couple projects. In my latest project I needed to upgrade to CCS6.2.0 to be able to use some new RTOS analysis features. CCS6.2.0 requires a full installation rather than updates through the Eclipse GUI so I decided to put it in a different directory than the CCS6.1.x version I had. My resulting folder structure looked like this:

C:/ti

- ccs_base (from ccs6.1 install)
- ccsv6 (original ccs6.1 install)
- ccsv62 (new ccs6.2.0 install)

  - ccs_base
  - ...

what's interesting to point out is how 6.1 placed `ccs_base` outside of the core ccsv6 folder whereas ccsv62 did not. So while I was updating my CCS6.2.0 installation with modules related to new IC targets I needed to build for, they were likely getting put into the wrong ccs_base folder because CCS was confused by the two concurrent installs.

So I uninstalled both CCS versions, rebooted my machine, and reinstalled only CCS6.2.0. I then added the modules I needed and tried re-importing the projects that were triggering the error. All turned out well and good.

So although I don't know precisely what was causing the problem, it definitely seemed to be related to confusion due to multiple CCS installations. Simply uninstalling older CCS versions and only having one instance of the app on your machine may correct the issue.